# Sonar, Gradle and Android returns 0 issue

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

**The problem**

I have an Android project that compiles and works correctly. It's "managed" by Gradle and continuously built with Jenkins. I would like to analyze my code quality with Sonar.

The Sonar analysis is made with the `sonarRunner` Gradle task. The problem is that Sonar still telling me that there is "0 issue"... (I can ensure you that there are errors... I add one myself to be sure...). However, it gives me other information like : number of lines of code, number of classes, comments and documentation percentages, duplication percentage, complexity... It's like Android Lint was not running.

**What I tried**

`lint` works like a charm... :

> Ran lint on variant armRelease: 153 issues found
>
> Ran lint on variant armDebug: 153 issues found
>
> Ran lint on variant x86Debug: 153 issues found
>
> Ran lint on variant x86Release: 153 issues found

I tried a lot of thing that I read over the Internet and SO :

- [Publishing Lint results to Sonar using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261007/publishing-lint-results-to-sonar-using-gradle)
- http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html
- https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android/blob/master/build.gradle

I had some different errors like "Class 'android/content/res/Resources' is not accessible through the ClassLoader." or something else, but I never was able to have a correct report).

**The details**

*Structure of the project*

```
- myProjectName
    | build
    | libs
    | src
        | debug
        | main
            | assets
            | java
                | com.myPackage...
            | jniLibs
            | res
            | AndroidManifest.xml
        | release
    | build.gradle
    | gradle.properties
    | settings.gradle
```

---

*settings.gradle*

Empty

---

*gradle.properties*

Empty

---

*build.gradle* (useless parts removed)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

/**********************************
 * Plugins declarations
 **********************************/
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

/**********************************
 * Sonar Runner configuration
 **********************************/
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://pic.url/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://pic.url/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "*****"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "*****"

        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.profile", "MyCompany Android"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
        property "sonar.analysis.mode", "analysis"

        properties["sonar.sources"] = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        properties["sonar.binaries"] = [file("build/intermediates/classes/x86/debug")]
    }
}

/**********************************
 * Android configuration
 **********************************/
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myPackage..."
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

---

As I tried a lot of thing, I don't any clue on what to try next. Please ask in comments if you need more information.

Last information :

- Sonar 3.7
- Gradle 1.12
- JVM 1.8.0_20 Oracle
- OS : Linux Fedora 20

**EDIT**

`gradle sonarRunner` log (asked in comments) : http://pastebin.com/uJwqpAkY

(all the '***' are here to hide company names, everything is normal :))

Comment: Would you be able to share the log of the analysis ?

Comment: If you tell me where I can found it, I will do it as soon as possible

Comment: How do you run your analysis with sonar-runner ? can you provide what is the output of the sonar-runner command ? (if it is on jenkins, this should be the log of the job)

Comment: I am running it with `gradle sonarRunner` command. I will add the log of this command.

Comment: I added logs of the sonarRunner task

Comment: For history, would be great to have it directly in the post rather than a link to an external resource. Thanks.

Comment: @benzonico : seeing the size of the log, I do not want to make my post so long... I will move it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `AndroidLintSensor` is not executed during your analysis. (otherwise you would see the line `Sensor AndroidLintSensor...` somewhere in your log.

This could be due to many reasons : Does your profile includes android rules ? Your project must have java files and an android manifest located in your base directory or your source directory to trigger the execution of the sensor (which will execute android lint).

(if you are curious, here is the part of the code that will trigger the execution of the sensor : [AndroidLintSensor.java](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-android/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/android/lint/AndroidLintSensor.java#L54-54) )

Comment: Thank you so much :) The AndroidManifest was not detected. I put it in the BaseDir and everything works perfectly now. I will try to place it  somewhere else and correctly set the SonarRunner. Still have all errors about ClassLoader, but it will be another question.

Comment: Adding a last comment : I put my AndroidManifest.xml in the `myProject/` (baseDir). It's not the default location. The default location is `myProject/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` (according to Android doc). For SonarRunner, sonar.sources has to be `myProject/src/main/java`. I should chose between following Android gradle Standard, and be compatible with SonarRunner. How can I become both of them ? :)